# C# - WPF ComboBox SelectedValue from Enum

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, enums, selectedvalue

I have a `ComboBox` in XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Form1Combobox" Width="150" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedValue="{Binding Dept}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=Depts}}"/>
```

My static resource is using an `ObjectDataProvider` to populate the `ComboBox` with values from an enum:

```
public enum Department
{
    Leadership,
    Maintenance,
    Salaried,
    Commission
}
```

I have an `ObservableCollection` of employees, where I set their Dept property to something (say, `Dept = Department.Leadership`). The employee class uses `INotifyPropertyChange`, for other things including a name. The `ComboBox` populates correctly, but it's initial value isn't being set.

My question is, how can I set the `SelectedValue` of the `ComboBox` to the appropriate property of the employee?

EDIT:
This is my observable collection (a snippet).

```
ObservableCollection<Employee> emps = new ObservableCollection<Employee>
{
    new Employee{Name = "Exam Pell", Title = "Manager", Phone = "(801) 555-2677", Email = "examPell@co.co", isActive = true, Dept = Department.Commission}, 
};
```

This is my static resource:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Depts" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="en:department+Department"></x:Type>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

I have actually noticed that whenever I attempt to set SelectedValue or SelectedItem, the combobox turns red (I have a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` that is also tied to this, but has an `ItemsSource`). Also, I have a `ListBox` that also shows the department - however, this one displays the correctly, but doesn't update even when I change the `ComboBox` selection for any employee.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting `SelectedValue` set `SelectedItem`.

To set `SelectedValue` you need to have set `DisplayMemberPath` and `ValueMemberPath`. In your case since its an Enum you can't set them.

So set `SelectedItem` like this

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Form1Combobox" 
          Width="150" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Dept}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=Depts}}"/>
```

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work. I can cycle through different employees, but the combobox doesn't change; it always shows the last selected value. Also, when I try to change the value for one employee, the combobox border goes red until I switch to another employee (where the value stays the same, but the red border is gone).

Comment: Show declaration for `Depts` and how you are filling it?